# How do I alter metaData on number, date and boolean columns in ExtJS 6.x using Sencha Architect?

Tags: extjs, extjs6.5.1

Per Sencha documentation, numbercolumn, datecolumn and booleancolumn does not have a renderer event. As logical as this sounds there is an inherent issue with not having a renderer event on these column types.

Example of a renderer function in a view controller to modify the background color when the LineNum of the record is in the array of warning line numbers.

```
renderCompanyID: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
    if (record.get('LineNum') > 0) {
        this.warningLineArr.forEach( function (item, index){
            if (item['LineNum'] == record.get('LineNum')) {
                metaData.style = "background-color: rgba(255, 184, 77, 0.25);";
                view.addRowCls(rowIndex, 'rec-warn');
            }
        });
    }
},
```

And the renderer in a gridcolumn definition is as follows

```
xtype: 'gridcolumn',
   renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
      Ext.fireEvent('renderCompanyID', value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view);
      return value;
  },
dataIndex: 'CompanyID',
text: 'Company ID'
```

And the results of this due to not having a renderer option on number and date columns is as follows:

[image: Rendered Results]

So the question is, is there an event, listener or attribute on number, date or boolean columns that would send the metaData to the handler whereby the metaData can be altered on conditions and a per row/cell basis?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you manually set `usingDefaultRenderer` to true, you would be able to use the renderer and call the `defaultRenderer` to render the value.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ftg

```
Ext.define(null, {
    override: 'Ext.grid.column.Number',
    usingDefaultRenderer: true
});

Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'employeeStore',
    fields: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'seniority', 'dep', 'hired'],
    data: [{
        firstname: "Michael",
        lastname: "Scott",
        seniority: 7,
        dep: "Management",
        hired: "01/10/2004"
    }, {
        firstname: "Dwight",
        lastname: "Schrute",
        seniority: 2,
        dep: "Sales",
        hired: "04/01/2004"
    }, {
        firstname: "Jim",
        lastname: "Halpert",
        seniority: 3,
        dep: "Sales",
        hired: "02/22/2006"
    }, {
        firstname: "Kevin",
        lastname: "Malone",
        seniority: 4,
        dep: "Accounting",
        hired: "06/10/2007"
    }, {
        firstname: "Angela",
        lastname: "Martin",
        seniority: 5,
        dep: "Accounting",
        hired: "10/21/2008"
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Column Demo',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'First Name',
        dataIndex: 'firstname'
    }, {
        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
        text: 'Seniority',
        dataIndex: 'seniority',
        renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
            return this.defaultRenderer(value);
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Hired Month',
        dataIndex: 'hired',
        xtype: 'datecolumn',
        format: 'M'
    }, {
        text: 'Department (Yrs)',
        xtype: 'templatecolumn',
        tpl: '{dep} ({seniority})'
    }],
    width: 400,
    forceFit: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: I should of been more clear stating I'm using Sencha Architect. This means I cannot manually add renderer to the column definition like it is done when manually coding.

Answer (score 1):

Your question may be an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so let me answer your underlying problem first.

If it's just line numbers, you wouldn't use the `meta` parameter of the `renderer` function.

Since your color is fixed, it's even more easy to use the [`getRowClass`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.view.Table.html#method-getRowClass) method like this:

```
xtype: 'grid',
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
        if (!record.get('LineNum')) return "";
        if(!Ext.isArray(this.ownerGrid.warningLineArr)) return "";
        if(this.ownerGrid.warningLineArr.indexOf(record.get('LineNum'))>-1) return "warning-row";
        return "";
    }
}
```

and then you would define a CSS class with the color:

```
.warning-row td {
    background-color: rgba(255, 184, 77, 0.25);
}
```

[Relevant fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fth) which also contains an answer to your question in the first place. Just in case you need it elsewhere on a single cell, it has the following override which updates meta info of a cell while using the default renderer:

```
Ext.define('MyOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.column.Column',
   initComponent: function() {
       var me = this;
       if(me.defaultRenderer) {
           var oldRenderer = me.defaultRenderer
           me.defaultRenderer = function() {
               if(this.updateMeta) this.updateMeta.apply(this, arguments);
               return oldRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
           };
       }
       return me.callParent(arguments);
   } 
});
```

Comment: I will check this out on Monday when at work. It looks like the viewConfig just may be what I'm looking for. I don't quite agree with using the override option and I should of added to my question that I'm working in the confines of Sencha Architect which has limitations compared to manual coding. I will also update my question to make it clear about Sencha Architect.