# Hide checkcell on render - extjs 6.5.3 modern

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs6-modern

I am trying to hide the `checkcell` of a `checkcolumn` if the value of another `column` is `null`. But unfortunately according to the [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer) *This config is only processed if the cell type is the default of Ext.grid.cell.Cell.*

So the solution with the `renderer` config won't work.

**For Example:**

```
{
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'isSomething',
        text: '',
        width: 30,
        menuDisabled: true,
        headerCheckbox: false,
        renderer: function(value, record) {
            var relatedValue = record.get('somethingElse');
            return relatedValue ? new Ext.grid.column.Check().renderer(value) : '';
        }
    }
```

Any tips or tricks to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`gridcell`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.grid.cell.Cell.html) and inside `gridcell` you can use [`checkbox`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.field.Checkbox.html) to achieve your requirement.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2g1g)**, I have created a demo using `gridcell` and `checkbox`. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create({

            xtype: 'grid',

            title: 'Tree Grid Demo',

            // itemConfig: {
            //     viewModel: true
            // },

            store: {

                fields: [{
                    name: 'isCheck',
                    defaultValue: true
                }],
                data: [{
                    firstname: "Michael",
                    lastname: "Scott",
                    seniority: 7,
                    department: "Management",
                    hired: "01/10/2004"
                }, {
                    firstname: "Dwight",
                    lastname: "Schrute",
                    seniority: 2,
                    department: "Sales",
                    hired: "04/01/2004"
                }, {
                    firstname: "Jim",
                    lastname: "Halpert",
                    seniority: 3,
                    department: "Sales",
                    hired: "02/22/2006"
                }, {
                    firstname: "Kevin",
                    lastname: "Malone",
                    seniority: 4,
                    department: '',
                    hired: "06/10/2007"
                }, {
                    firstname: "Angela",
                    lastname: "Martin",
                    seniority: 5,
                    department: "Accounting",
                    hired: "10/21/2008"
                }]
            },

            columns: [{
                text: 'First Name',
                dataIndex: 'firstname'
            }, {
                text: 'Last Name',
                dataIndex: 'lastname'
            }, {
                text: 'Hired Month',
                dataIndex: 'hired'
            }, {
                text: '',
                width: 30,
                renderer: function (value, record, index, cell) {
                    if (record.get('department')) {
                        cell.setTools({
                            xtype: 'checkbox',
                            checked: record.get('isCheck')
                        });
                    } else {
                        return '';
                    }
                }

                /*cell: {
                    tools: {
                        xtype: 'checkbox',
                        bind: {
                            hidden: '{!record.department}',
                            checked: '{record.isCheck}'
                        }
                    }
                }*/
            }],

            fullscreen: true
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks N. Jadhav. I am going to try to implement it on my code. Your fiddle works like charm.

Comment: Saddly i am on MVC not on MVVM but i'll figure it out.

Comment: @Απόπατος I have updated my answer without mvvm and [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2g1g) as well. Please check

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949615/how-do-i-alter-metadata-on-number-date-and-boolean-columns-in-extjs-6-x-using-s/49952239#49952239), when you add the override to your code, you can use the following:

```
Ext.util.CSS.createStyleSheet('.hideCheck .x-grid-checkcolumn::after { content: \'\' }');
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    columns: [{
        xtype:'checkcolumn',
        updateMeta: function(v, meta, record) {
            if(v===null) meta.tdCls = "hideCheck";
        }
```

[Relevant fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2g1f)

Comment: Would this work for modern too? Because my question is about modern.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be the usage of the *hidden* property of the cell.

Hint: This property is marked as **private**!

```
{   
    xtype: 'grid',
    store: store,

    itemConfig: {
        viewModel: true
    },

    columns: [{
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        text: 'Boolean',
        dataIndex: 'bool',
        width: 200,
        cell: {
            hideMode: 'visibility',
            bind: {
                hidden: '{!record.bool}'
            }
        },
    }]
}
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2q28)

Answer (score 0):

```
                            <Renderer  Handler="if(record.data.Field !== null && record.data.Field.length &gt; 0){
                                      return true;
                                               }else{
                                      return false;
                                                } "/>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer and explain how and why it solves the original problem?